# M-x compile, Compilation Command Variable

Tags: compilation

When M-x compile and specifying a compilation command, where is this command stored?

I'd like to use whatever it's stored to, in a function to quickly compile, instead of being prompted for the compile command.

```
(defun my-build ()
""
(interactive)
  (compile "variable"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can specify per-buffer compilation commands using the "local variables" section or hooks. See the docstring of `compile-command` variable. The default is "make -k ". Here is what I have for an example `.c` file.

```
// Local Variables:
// compile-command: "gcc cpp10.c -o cpp10 -lm "
// End:
```

Emacs will now autofill the "Compile command" with the above string whenever you visit the buffer and run `compile`, and you just need to confirm.

You can invoke "M-x recompile" to reuse the last compilation command and completely avoid the confirmation prompt. The variable `compile-command` is updated to reflect the last used compilation command. The information does not persist across Emacs sessions.

Answer (score 1):

When I run `C-h f compile`, it shows a link to the code. Clicking that links opens the file in Emacs. Reading the code, I see, as Swarnendu did, that `compile-command` is the variable the code uses to save the compile command. Using `C-h v compile-command` shows useful information about `compile-command`.